# Filling a field inside a select stamenet - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to do calculations and fill a field inside a select statement. It looks like this:

```
    CREATE VIEW SALES_REPORT AS(
SELECT 
INVOICENO,
INVOICEDATE,
CLIENTID,
CONTACT,
INVOICEJOBNO,
ADDCHARGES,
CHARGESINFO,
EMPLOYEEID,
USUALPAY,
VAT,
SUBTOTAL (SELECT(USUALPAY * COUNT(*) AS SUBTOTAL FROM SALES_REPORT)),
TOTAL = (SUBTOTAL * VAT)
FROM SALES_REPORT_JOINS_CONFIG
GROUP BY INVOICENO ORDER BY INVOICEDATE DESC);
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: So are you just getting errors when you do this, or is this something where the contents are dynamic, to be determined at run-time?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, but the subtotal should be filled and is set to null, with phpmyadmin thinking my select statement is aprt of the field name.

Answer (score 0):

```
TOTAL = (SUBTOTAL * VAT)
```

should probably be

```
(SUBTOTAL * VAT) AS TOTAL
```

right now it's going to return the boolean true/false result of an equality comparison. You're NOT assigning the multiplication results to a 'total' field - you're comparing whatever value is in total to the result of the multiplication.

and this is a flat-out syntax error:

```
SUBTOTAL (SELECT(USUALPAY * COUNT(*) AS SUBTOTAL FROM SALES_REPORT)),
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that sorted my problem!